# Converting PDFs to PNGs with Dragonfly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, imagemagick, dragonfly-gem

I have a Dragonfly processor which should take a given PDF and return a PNG of the first page of the document.

When I run this processor via the console, I get back the PNG as expected, however, when in the context of Rails, I'm getting it as a PDF.

My code is roughly similar to this:

```
  def to_pdf_thumbnail(temp_object)
    tempfile = new_tempfile('png')
    args = "'#{temp_object.path}[0]' '#{tempfile.path}'"
    full_command = "convert #{args}"
    result = `#{full_command}`
    tempfile
  end

  def new_tempfile(ext=nil)
    tempfile = ext ? Tempfile.new(['dragonfly', ".#{ext}"]) : Tempfile.new('dragonfly')
    tempfile.binmode
    tempfile.close
    tempfile
  end
```

Now, tempfile is definitely creating a .png file, but the convert is generating a PDF (when run from within Rails 3).

Any ideas as to what the issue might be here?  Is something getting confused about the content type?

I should add that both this and a standard conversion (`asset.png.url`) both yield a PDF with the PDF content as a small block in the middle of the (A4) image.

Comment: Can you post your controller code that Rails is using to send the result?

Comment: No - there is no real controller here, it's all internal to Dragonfly

Answer (score 4):

An approach I’m using for this is to generate the thumbnail PNG on the fly via the `thumb` method from Dragonfly’s ImageMagick plugin:

```
<%= image_tag rails_model.file.thumb('100x100#', format: 'png', frame: 0).url %>
```

So long as Ghostscript is installed, ImageMagick/Dragonfly will honour the format / frame (i.e. page of the PDF) settings. If `file` is an image rather than a PDF, it will be converted to a PNG, and the frame number ignored (unless it’s a GIF).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def to_pdf_thumbnail(temp_object)
  ret = ''
  tempfile = new_tempfile('png')
  system("convert",tmp_object.path[0],tmpfile.path)
  tempfile.open {|f| ret = f.read }
  ret
end
```

The problem is you are likely handing convert ONE argument not two

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't convert rely on the extension to determine the type?  Are you sure the tempfiles have the proper extensions?